# How to convert Oracle type object to Java object using Hibernate / JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Basically what I'm trying to do is a call to Oracle stored procedure using Hibernate. Procedure takes two IN parameters, creates object of Oracle type User (it has two fields - id and name) and returns it via OUT parameter. My Java call is:

```
ProcedureCall call = session.createStoredProcedureCall("get_obj");
call.registerParameter(1, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(1L);
call.registerParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue("John");
call.registerParameter(3, User.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
```

Java class is simple POJO class with same fields, setters and getters. Is there a way to convert Oracle types to Java and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Using Customized Type Mappings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html) you should create a `User` class by implementing [`SQLData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLData.html) interface:

```
public class User implements SQLData {
  // fields
  // readSQL
  // writeSQL
}
```

and then use [`Connection.setTypeMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setTypeMap(java.util.Map)) to setup the mapping for new `User` type.

Comment: is it same in hibernate,for pure jdbc I use it but in hibernate?